# How do I disable dialogs and popups made by an ActiveX control?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, activex

I have a WebBrowser control in my Winforms application, I load a wabpage that contains ActiveX content, there is a control(That I want to keep it running) that generates a dialog box, when this box is closed a popup is made. How do I stop the dialog box from coming up and the popup for annoying the user???

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't modify behavior of external program or control in a way that not designed by author.

Your options

- some controls have API to modify behavior - check documentation
- solve the reason dialog or popup is shown for. I.e. provide proof of purchase.
- find the window and hide it using Win32 APIs

Comment: The developers of the ActiveX control are gone, and I cannot purchase the control anymore!